# match some string

Tags: regex

I want to make a regex that match 
baking.asp
nhdjdl.asp
hdghgdh.asp
hksks.asp

but not any file starting with http:// like

http://hhhdjg.asp

How can I make that since I do not know how to say except this sequence of character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative lookahead assertions.

```
>>> re.match('(?!http://).*\\.asp', 'http://foo.asp')
>>> re.match('(?!http://).*\\.asp', 'foo.asp')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f34f8432920>
```

Comment: @user651521: it doesn't. As you can see, the first example matches nothing (because the prompt shows up on the next line). The second one matches "foo.asp".

Answer (score 0):

If you also expect to exclude string starting with ftp://, etc:

```
>>> re.match('[^/]*\.asp', '/tmp/foo.asp')
>>> re.match('[^/]*\.asp', 'http://foo.asp')
>>> re.match('[^/]*\.asp', 'ftp://foo.asp')
>>> re.match('[^/]*\.asp', 'foo.asp')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2abe856856b0>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to find all patterns that match '*.asp" , and from that throwing out any results that begin with "http:" . Since you don't know regular expressions (and presumably your teammates don't either, if you have them), a non-regexp solution will be the most clear.

For example:

```
[s for s in list_of_strings if s.endswith(".asp") and not s.startswith("http://")]
```